# Prevent roslyn (omnisharp) analysis of EF Core migrations classes

Tags: c#, visual-studio-code, roslyn-code-analysis, omnisharp, editorconfig

I'm using the c# plugin (roslyn-omnisharp) in vscode.

The analyser reports warnings in my EF Core migrations classes.

I want to prevent that, so I added an `.editorconfig` in that directory:

```
root = true
[{[0-9]*.cs,ContextModelSnapshot.cs}]
generated_code = true
dotnet_analyzer_diagnostic.severity = none
```

I also tried:

```
root = true
[**.cs]
generated_code = true
dotnet_analyzer_diagnostic.severity = none
```

But the analyser ignores all that and still reports warnings.

How can I do this?